# get a substring not knowing the length c++

Tags: c++, string

While reading a c++ e-book, I imagined a next question:

Suppose we have a string `str` of an arbitrary length. This string has two words `start` and `end`. The idea is to get a substring of a string between those `start` and `end`. Is there any way to get a result similar to that from `string::substr` but without knowing the distance between `start` and `end`? I mean, of course, that is easy to do with `copy` and iterators or any loop. But maybe there is a method implemented in `string`? I could not find one in c++ reference.

Comment: You have to write something yourself, or maybe a regular expression could do this.

Comment: std::string::find, then substr ?

Comment: _"This string has two words ..."_ So you actually want to parse a _space delimited string_, or what?

Comment: find "start", find "end" then take substr delimited by 2 positions you found.. just like deviantfan said ^^

Comment: @deviantfan Yes, we will find 'start' but writing 'str.substr(str.find("start", 0), ?)' wont give the effect. I want to cut everything but substring between those words.

Comment: @VVG As Dario00 said, you´ll need a second find, and you need to check the return values, and choose a proper start position for the second find, and and and... Read the docs. And yes, then it will work.

Comment: @VVG What is word? For example does string "startxyz" contain word "start"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution is to find first occurrence os "start" and last occurrence of "end":

```
string get_substr_between_start_and_end(const string& s)
{
    size_t start_pos = s.find("start");
    size_t end_pos = s.rfind("end");

    if((end_pos != string::npos) && (start_pos < end_pos)) //both are present
    {
        start_pos += 5; //skip "start"
        return s.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos);
    }

    return "";
}
```

If either "start" or "end" is not present, empty string is returned. This function will work properly with any number of "start"s and "end"s. Example:

```
int main()
{
    string str_1 = "start and something between end";
    string str_2 = "start and something between end and another end";
    string str_3 = "start and second start and something between end and another end";

    cout<<get_substr_between_start_and_end(str_1)<<endl;
    cout<<get_substr_between_start_and_end(str_2)<<endl;
    cout<<get_substr_between_start_and_end(str_3)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 and something between 
 and something between end and another 
 and second start and something between end and another
```

Live sample: [LINK](https://ideone.com/28mGPB).

Comment: In general case "end" can be before "start".:)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string that contains data and you want to get all of the string between a starting and ending bit of text you can use the following.

```
std::string test = "this is a string we are searching through to get a substring";
std::string startText = "string";
std::string endText = "to";
size_t startPos, endPos;

startPos = test.find(startText, 0);
if (startPos == std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "No Starting Text";

endPos = test.find(endText, startPos + 1);
if (endPos == std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "No Ending Text";

std::string subString = test.substr(startPos + startText.size() + 1, endPos - startPos + startText.size());
std::cout << subString;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the task in different ways either using member functions of class std::string or standard algorithms.

Here are presented the two approaches
The first one uses member functions of class `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "startmiddleend" );
    const char *start = "start";
    const char *end = "end";
    std::string t;

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    auto pos = s.find( start );
    if ( pos != std::string::npos )
    {
        pos += std::strlen( start );
        auto n = s.find( end, pos );
        if ( n == std::string::npos ) n = s.size();

        t = s.substr( pos, n - pos );
    }

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

The second one uses standard algorithm `std::search`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "startmiddleend" );
    const char *start = "start";
    const char *end = "end";
    std::string t;

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    size_t n = std::strlen( start );

    auto first = std::search( s.begin(), s.end(), start, start + n );

    if ( first != s.end() )
    {
        std::advance( first, n );        
        t.assign( first, std::search( first, s.end(), end, end + std::strlen( end ) ) );
    }

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

The both program have the same output

The program output is

```
startmiddleend
middle
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is **no** there is not a simple method to extract such text.

I happen to have a function I prepared earlier that does this itteratively. I'll provide it in case it proves useful to someone:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using size_type = std::string::size_type;

size_type extract_delimited_text(const std::string& in
    , const std::string& d1, const std::string& d2
    , std::string& out, size_type pos = 0)
{
    auto end = pos;

    if((pos = in.find(d1, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if((end = in.find(d2, (pos = pos + d1.size()))) != std::string::npos)
        {
            out = in.substr(pos, end - pos);
            return end + d2.size();
        }
    }
    return std::string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    std::string d1 = "${";
    std::string d2 = "}";

    std::string s = "find stuff ${to extract} and stuff and ${some more} stuff";

    std::string sub;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;

    // keep extracting all matches
    while((pos = extract_delimited_text(s, d1, d2, sub, pos)) != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "sub: " << sub << '\n';

}
```

**Output:**

```
sub: to extract
sub: some more
```